# How to block website on windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I am currently using windows 8.1 I want to block some website without using any sophisticated software  I tried the most common method i.e changing the permission to the files C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts and add the lines like: 127.0.0.1      www.yahoo.com but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: try adding `127.0.0.1 yahoo.com` to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the permissions - you just edit the content of the host file

Make sure you open / edit it as admin and save it without any extensions

The format is as following:

> 127.0.0.1 www.yahoo.com #comment - no more yahoo

[here is steps by step for Windows 8](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cleared your browser-cache and verified that it's not working via hosts-file (which should work perfectly) you maybe can configure your router to block the domain.